# How to install c++ program into conda environment from source

Tags: c++, makefile, conda

I would like to compile and then use the scientific project [BASS](https://github.com/judyboon/BASS), which is distributed as c++ source code on github. I've set up a conda environment `bass` to hold everything related to BASS, and I'd like to compile BASS into this environment (so that if I delete the environment, it's cleanly removed).

I don't know if I should be using `conda-build` or `make` to do this. There is a Makefile distributed with the project, but I think it might have an error.

My latest try is the following: (the source files are in `code/` and `gsl` seems to be a dependency):

```
conda create -n bass
conda activate bass
conda install make
conda install gsl
cd code/  
make
```

I get the following:

```
gcc -c main.cpp -I../Libs/GSL/include/ -I./
main.cpp:19:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_statistics.h' file not found
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:11: main.o] Error 1
```

My questions:

- should I be doing this with make?
- do I need gcc/g++/cxx-compiler installed in my conda env?
- is the Makefile correct where it says "`-I../Libs/GSL/include/`"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic Conda recipe for the package. Make a folder (say `recipe`) and put the following two files in it:

**meta.yaml**

```yaml
package:
  name: bass
  version: 0.1  # this is totally arbitrary (there are no versions)

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/judyboon/BASS.git

requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
  host:
    - gsl
  run:
    - gsl

about:
  home: https://github.com/judyboon/BASS
  license: GPL-3.0-only
  license_file: COPYING
  license_family: GPL
```

**build.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

## change to source dir                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
cd ${SRC_DIR}/code

## compile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
${CXX} -c main.cpp *.cpp -I./ ${CXXFLAGS}

## link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
${CXX} *.o -o BASS -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm ${LDFLAGS}

## install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
mkdir -p $PREFIX/bin
cp BASS ${PREFIX}/bin/BASS
```

You can then build this with `conda build .`, run from in that directory.

### Installing

After successful build, you can create an environment with this package installed using

```bash
conda create -n foo --use-local bass
```

Since I'm on an Intel architecture, and this tool uses CBLAS, I would further specify to use MKL:

```bash
conda create -n foo --use-local bass blas=*=*mkl
```

Now if you activate the environment `foo` (that's an arbitrary name), the software will be on PATH, under the binary `BASS`.

---

### Additional Notes

I verified this works on **osx-64** platform with the `conda-forge` channel prioritized.

The `Makefile` accompanying the code isn't very generic. Here we just have it compile all `.cpp` files and subsequently link all `.o` files.

There aren't any releases on the repository, so the versioning in the `meta.yaml` is arbitrary.

The `build.sh` defines the final output binary as `BASS` - that could be changed, and differs from the original Makefile which outputs the binary as `main`.

Comment: I also had to download the MacOSX10.10 SDK due to the `ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file` error and follow instructions [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9096) to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you write, the correct way is to build a conda recipe. By writing a recipe the `conda` knows what to delete, when you delete the environment.

The recipe is a text file (the `meta.yaml` file), where you write some metadata describing the package, define dependencies and write a short build script that executes the make file and installs the binaries to correct location. Defining the compilation environment may not be trivial and you should follow the documentation for the package you are trying to install. If there are problems with the package code (that includes the makefile) that's something conda can't help you with.

See the documentation on how to write the recipe:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/concepts/recipe.html

When you've got the recipe complete, then you would run the `conda build` and `conda install -c [path to the build] [the package name]` (I'm writing this because it took me ages to realize how to correctly install a local package.)

Comment: FYI: To install a locally built package, just add a `--use-local` flag - no need to specify path. That is, `conda install --use-local pkg_name` should work.